# In which components can geth be split?

Tags: go-ethereum, p2p

I'm interested in how does the process "geth" (in a full node) work. I mean in which components can the geth **conceptually** be split.

In my understanding there should be at least (conceptually) three components:

1. One component should keep the connection with the other peers (to maintain the p2p network)
2. One component should process the blockchain and check the validity of the information (execute smart contracts and so on)
3. One component should listen to incoming RPC calls and responds accordingly

Can we identify other components?

Comment: Geth is written in Go, so it's unlikely it uses explicit threads in the way you describe.

Comment: I edited the question. Could you please take a look to It and say to me if it is now acceptable? Thanks.

Comment: Geth is really complex piece of software, it has to deal with different tasks: communication with other nodes, storage an retrieval of blockchain data, execution of smart contracts, personal account management, json-rpc programable api, etc. And it is evolving all the time so an analysis of geth will get out of date quickly.